# WPF: ListBox item show from bottom to top

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I think title is not clear
I am working with WPF and creating `custom Messages control`. I have `message User Control` and the message user controls showing in `custom Messages control`[`ListBox`].
**XAML code:**

```
 <ListBox x:Name="uiMessages" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Messages}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <wpfMessages:MessageDisplay>

                    </wpfMessages:MessageDisplay>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Current view:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Now list box item is showing from top to bottom and after red message there empty space. I will be good whem the 2 green messages will bi in bottom and red one in top. Expected is add messages from botton to top no from top to botton like now.
[image]

any Ideas?

Thanks in advance Jamaxack!

Comment: Just to clarify, the desired result is a wrap panel that fills right top left horizontally and wraps upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created custom `WrapPanel` that reverses Elements
**XAML code:**

```
 <ListBox x:Name="uiMessages" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
         <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <wpf:ReverseWrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   </ListBox>
```

**Code behind**:

```
  public class ReverseWrapPanel : WrapPanel
    {
        public new Orientation Orientation { get { return base.Orientation; } set { base.Orientation = value; ResetAll(); } }

        /// <summary>
        /// The opposite of the Orientation property.
        /// </summary>
        Orientation FlipDirection { get { return Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? Orientation.Vertical : Orientation.Horizontal; } }

        public ReverseWrapPanel()
        {
            Initialized += ReverseWrapPanel_Initialized;
        }

        void ReverseWrapPanel_Initialized(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Mirror(FlipDirection);
        }

        protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
        {
            base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);

            foreach (UIElement child in Children.OfType<UIElement>())
            {
                child.Mirror(FlipDirection);
            }
        }

        void ResetAll()
        {
            this.Mirror(FlipDirection);

            foreach (UIElement child in Children.OfType<UIElement>())
            {
                child.Mirror(FlipDirection);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanx Jamshed!

Answer (score 4):

It is a little unclear but I think you want to change the ItemsPanel Layout.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i need WrapPanel, if messages more than 3 than I can not see another messages in stack panel, wrap panel wraps and adds to second row messages that i cant see

Comment: From the msdn "Subsequent ordering happens sequentially from top to bottom or from right to left depending on the orientation". Hence you are stuck with top to bottom. You can either write your own control or just modify your bound collection of items so that when you add an element you are adding it to the beginning instead of the end of the collection. Hint: Use a stack =P

Comment: This still won't get you quite the exact ordering as detailed by your picture. I don't think it is possible to get the exact ordering you described using a wrap panel without also rotating both the layout control and the layout elements 180 degrees.

Comment: I posted my solution in bottom